# Convert value of one cell into many rows, same ID value

Tags: excel

I have one cell like this:

`930    "<h2>Crawford, 1963-</h2> [wpse_playlist type=""audio""    tracklist=""true"" tracknumbers=""true"" images=""true"" artist=""true""] [wpse_trac title=""Indian Summer"" src=""http://urlnamehere/bitstream/handle/2374.UC/731507 /Elliston_Marisa_Crawford_01-10-14_Track_01.mp3?sequence=7""  type=""audio/mpeg"" caption="""" description="""" meta_artist=""Crawford,  Marisa & Pendarvis, Jack, 1963-"" meta_length_formatted="""" thumb_src="""" image_width=""300""][wpse_trac title=""The River"" src=""http://urlnamehere/bitstream/handle/2374.UC/731507/Elliston_Marisa_Crawford_01-10-14_Track_02.mp3?sequence=8"" type=""audio/mpeg"" caption="""" description="""" meta_artist=""Crawford, Marisa & Pendarvis, Jack, 1963-"" meta_length_formatted="""" thumb_src="""" image_width=""300""][wpse_trac title=""Swimming in Lanes Five and Six`

I'd like to break it up so that I get one row for each title value and src value, while keeping the same id (930 in this case. Thus:

Row 1:

`930 | wpse_trac title=""Indian Summer" | src=""http://urlnamehere/bitstream/handle/2374.UC/731507 /Elliston_Marisa_Crawford_01-10-14_Track_01.mp3?sequence=7"`

Row 2

`930 | [wpse_trac title=""The River"" src=""http://urlnamehere/bitstream/handle/2374.UC/731507/Elliston_Marisa_Crawford_01-10-14_Track_02.mp3?sequence=8`

Comment: What is your criteria for breaking up a line? Starts with 930? Ends with 'sequence=' and a number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following formula if your text is in cell A1 and drag the formula down:

```
=MID($A$1,1,SEARCH(" ",$A$1)-1)&" | "&MID($A$1,SEARCH("£wpse_trac title",SUBSTITUTE($A$1,"wpse_trac title","£wpse_trac title",ROW(A1))),SEARCH("£http:",SUBSTITUTE($A$1,"http:","£http:",ROW(A1)))-SEARCH("£wpse_trac title",SUBSTITUTE($A$1,"wpse_trac title","£wpse_trac title",ROW(A1)))-8)&" | "&MID($A$1,SEARCH("£http:",SUBSTITUTE($A$1,"http:","£http:",ROW(A1)))-6,SEARCH(" ",$A$1,SEARCH("£sequence",SUBSTITUTE($A$1,"sequence","£sequence",ROW(A1))))+10-SEARCH("£http:",SUBSTITUTE($A$1,"http:","£http:",ROW(A1)))-6)
```

[image: string substitute]

Answer (score 1):

1. Place the text in cell `A1`.
2. Go to `Data` tab and select `Text to Columns`
3. Choose `Delimited` and press `Next`.
4. Check `Other:` and key in `]` and press `Next`.
5. In `Destination`, select a cell other than `A1` and click `Finish`.

You will see your original text separated into many columns. At this point follow the following steps:

1. Press `Ctrl+H` in your keyboard to open the replace text dialog.
   In `Find what:`, enter `" type*` and click `Replace All`.
2. Select all the cells that have the resulting data, copy them and
   paste them as `Transpose` to paste them in rows instead of columns.
3. Remove the first and last cells (which are not desired)

Complete the desired task with some tiny touches made by you. `ENJOY`